# Remote SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, docker, docker-container

I am using Microsoft SQL Server on my mac through a docker container. I currently have a database on my local host. I want to share it with another computer/user so that they can get access to the DBMS and use C#. They are getting a error something like 'the server is not found or accessible'. 
How can i make the database remote?

Answer (score 0):

search for **my.conf** file in container.

```
whereis mysql
```

change bind address value:

```
bind-address   0.0.0.0
```

Then try to connect remotely:

```
mysql -h <host-name> -P <port> -u <user-name> -p
```

Comment: its not mysql though. Im using Microsoft sql server